# Does $\mathrm{correlation}(X, Y)=1$ imply $Y = aX + b$?

Tags: probability

I feel confused for the past solution in [Proving $Y = aX + b$ given correlation coefficient $|\rho(X, Y)| = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478137/proving-y-ax-b-given-correlation-coefficient-rhox-y-1), which tells $\rm{correlation}(X,Y)=1$ implies $Y = aX + b$ in contrast with the solution below:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables, $\sigma_x = \sqrt{\rm{Var}(X)}$, then

$$\rm{Var}\left(\frac{X}{\sigma_x} - \frac{Y}{\sigma_y}\right) = \rm{Var}\left(\frac{X}{\sigma_x}\right) + \rm{Var}\left(\frac{Y}{\sigma_y}\right)-2\rm{Cov}\left(\frac{X}{\sigma_x}, \frac{Y}{\sigma_y}\right) = 2-2\rm{Corr(X,Y)}$$

and let $\rm{Corr}(X, Y)=1$, then

$$\rm{Var}\left(\frac{X}{\sigma_x} - \frac{Y}{\sigma_y}\right) = 0 \implies \frac{X}{\sigma_x} - \frac{Y}{\sigma_y} = c$$

It seems $\rm{correlation}(X,Y)=1$ can NOT imply $Y = aX + b$. Could someone please tell which version is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we must have $Y=aX+b$ for some constants $a,b$ (with probability $1$). In your working, when you deduce that $$\dfrac{X}{\sigma_X} - \dfrac{Y}{\sigma_Y}=c,$$ this implies that $Y = aX+b$ for some constants $a,b$ (just rearrange the equation to express $Y$ in terms of $X$ to see this).